# XML Tags to bash variables

Tags: xml, awk, sed, grep, xmlstarlet

I am using the following curl command:

```
curl  -u $username:$password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | \tr -d '\n'
```

To get a sample output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">

<title>Gmail - Inbox for user@email.com</title>
<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>
<fullcount>13</fullcount>


<entry>
    <title>Backup Status</title>
    <summary>Backup Successful </summary>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=user@email.com&amp;message_id=1715ed8b619b4e4b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html"/>
    <modified>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</modified>
    <issued>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</issued>
    <id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1663333312794531403</id>
    <author>
        <name>Carbonite</name>
        <email>noreply@carbonite.com</email>
    </author>
</entry>
<entry>
    <title>Backup Status Report</title>
    <summary>Dear IDrive User, Ref : UserName....</summary>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=user@email.com&amp;message_id=1715ed8b619b4e4b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html"/>
    <modified>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</modified>
    <issued>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</issued>
    <id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1663333312794531403</id>
    <author>
        <name>no-reply</name>
        <email>no-reply@idrive.com</email>
    </author>
</entry>    

<entry>
    <title>Notification</title>
    <summary>Notification Status</summary>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=user@email.com&amp;message_id=1715ed8b619b4e4b&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html"/>
    <modified>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</modified>
    <issued>2020-04-07T19:53:47Z</issued>
    <id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1663333312794531403</id>
    <author>
        <name>Software Notification</name>
        <email>noreply@.email.com</email>
    </author>
</entry>

<entry>
  ............etc
</entry>
```

I would like to extract the values of all `<entry\title>`,`<entry\summary>`,`<entry\author\name>` and set them to variables in a bash script.

How can I set these values to variables?

I want to extract the values from the xml and send them to variables like this `<title>` to $title , `<summary>` to $summary and `<name>` to $name.

So an example would be:

$title = Email Title

$summary = Email Body

$name = from name

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: I added more information of what I am looking for. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This looks like something I am trying to do: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500401/set-bash-variables-from-xml-tags

Comment: @EdMorton I retyped my question, I hope it is clear what I am asking,

Comment: `$subject: <title>` is just some kind of template for your expected output, it's not your expected output. `$subject: Gmail - Inbox for user@email.com` would possibly be one line of your expected output because it shows output that includes data values from your input in a new format. So, one last time, please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input so we can help you and see [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I added the expected output. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213571/discussion-between-vlad-and-ed-morton).

Comment: @EdMorton How about now?

Comment: If your REAL input always contains **exactly** the string `Email Title` between title tags and **exactly** the string `Email Body` between summary tags and **exactly** the string `from name` between name tags, each of those repeated 3 times in different HTML blocks, and then you want your output to just contain 1 single occurrence of each of those strings then you would have done what I suggested and posted a [mcve] with sample input and expected output but if that was really what you wanted then you could just write `echo "\$title = Email Title\n\$summary = Email Body\n\$name = from name"`.

Comment: Tools like awk and sed are not best to parsing xml - they don't 'understand' the full structure of the file. Have you considered more advanced tools?

Comment: @EdMorton I see what you are talking about, I used email title because it can be a range of email titles, email body, and from names. I changed the questions once more

Comment: Your sample output has multiple `<title>`s, `<name>`s, etc. Are you trying to create multiple variables for each (as in `$title1`, `$title2`, etc.)?

Comment: @JackFleeting What I want to do if possible is to have it loop through the variables. So it will get the variables from each iteration and insert them into a table.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

First, to use xmlstarlet to assign values to variables, use these:

```
title=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//entry/title" input.xml)
name= $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//entry/author/name" input.xml)
summary = $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//entry/summary" input.xml)
```

In your sample xml, there are 3 values (from 3 emails) assigned to each variable. To access those in, for example, `$title` use:

```
for val in "${title[@]}";
do
  printf "$val\n"
done
```

Output:

```
Backup Status
Backup Status Report
Notification
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I get home. instead of a file input using input.xml, can i use a variable, such as xml_var=curl  -u $.....? Thank you

Comment: @vlad - Yes, you can probably use curl and pipe it into xmlstarlet; something like `curl -g "some url"  -s | xmlstarlet sel ...."`.